# Fine tune a part of a caffemodel, and save all parameters at last

Tags: caffe

I want to fine-tune a model from an existed caffemodel. But a part of this model I needn't run it, and I want to save this part's parameters at last, how can I do?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can set `lr_mult` for the layers you do not fine tune to zero. As long as they exist in your model, their parameters will be saved with all other parameters when you `save` the fine-tune net to a new caffemodel

Comment: I needn't some layers to do computing(forward & backward) in fine-tune process. I think if I can let them not do computing, then I can save some training time. Does this can be realized? Thank you very much~